# Bash command accessing all subdirectory fails

Tags: bash, gzip

I have a directory structure like this:

```
example/ace/actives_final.sdf.gz
example/ace/decoys_final.sdf.gz
example/aces/actives_final.sdf.gz
example/aces/decoys_final.sdf.gz
```

I only want to access each subdirectory and unzip the files...
I used

```
for D in `find . -maxdepth 1 -type d`; do gzip actives_final.sdf.gz; gzip -d decoys_final.sdf.gz; done
```

Also, for the for-part, I replaced the whole part from "for" to the first ";" with the given lines:

- `for i in ./*;`
- `for i in */;`

All of these variations seem to work for the first directory, ace.

Then, I get the errors

```
gzip: actives_final.sdf.gz: No such file or directory; 
gzip: decoys_final.sdf.gz: No such file or directory
```

three times, which fits, as this directory includes, apart from `ace`, two hidden directories and `aces`.

But I checked the spelling in the aces-directory several times and gzip should be able to find them, they are the same as in `ace`.

I am a bash beginner and I am afraid that I made some obvious mistake...

Edit: I only used this limited structure as a test, later, there will be more .gz in each directory, but not all of them should be unpacked, which is why I have to search for the full name. Also, if the unpacking works, I have to perform yet another command in these subdirectories, which is why I have to use a for loop.

Comment: Yes, the extracted files should be in the same subdirectory as the .gz ones.

Comment: No, I meant that I replaced the whole part from "for" to the first ";" with the given lines. Sorry for not making that clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a `for`-loop here. `find` should be enough:

```
find -name "*.gz" -exec gunzip {} \;
```

In this command, `find` searches recursively for files ending with `.gz` and extracts them using `gunzip` in their location.

---

If you need a loop, you can do the following:

```
for dir in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d)
do
  echo "entering $dir"
  cd "$dir"
  gunzip actives_final.sdf.gz
  gunzip decoys_final.sdf.gz
  cd -
done
```

In this loop, you are entering each directory (`cd "$dir"`), executing your `gunzip` commands and then going back to the previous directory (`cd -`) to start the next iteration.

Comment: Is there no way with a for loop? I edited my question to show why I need one.

Comment: @LizzAlice of course ;-) see my edit

Comment: Of course, thank you! Now I see what my mistake was, I went into the first directory and never went back out...